# How would I use JavaScript to make the reset button actually work?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Consider the following code:

```
  var animalSound = document.getElementById("animalSound");
```

Reset button:

```
   var resetButton = document.querySelector("#reset");
```

The function my console says that the value is `null`:

```
 resetButton.addEventListener("click", function(){
   alert(" clicked button");
 })
```

The animals it picks from:

```
 var animals = ["elephant", "dog", "monkey", "zebra", 
           "parakeet", "cat", "pig", "Guerilla", 
           "skunk", "Leapord" ]


 var x = animals[Math.floor(Math.random()*animals.length)];
 animalSound.textContent =  x;
```

Comment: So what does "actually working" entail: what are you trying to achieve and what is going wrong?

Comment: *"the function my console says that the value is null"* Possible duplicate of [*Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

Comment: I am trying to set a value so when i click the button it resets the list and the game starts over

Comment: @T.J.Crowder That's not the question really.

Comment: @JonathanRys - Congratulations on your mind-reading skills. :-)

Comment: This is a challenging question, because there's not a lot of information to work with.  When you say, "How would I use JS to make the reset button actually work", and you just leave the code, those are two useful pieces of information.  However, part of diagnosing the problem such that you can be better-advised, is noting what is actually happening - is the reset button doing nothing?  Is the reset button behaving incorrectly some other way?  Because we don't know this, it's hard to give you guidance on what a better fix would look like.

Comment: I found it confusing at first too, but I just pasted the code into the editor, read the comments, and tried to run it.  The problem explained itself better with that approach.  English is a lot harder for some people than JavaScript ;) New posters think we can just read code too.

Comment: A [MCVE] which provides all context is always helpful. Without your HTML we don't know if you are selecting your elements correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I would put the code to choose the random animal into a function and call it on click:

```js
var resetButton = document.querySelector("#reset");

resetButton.addEventListener("click", function(){
  setNewAnimal()
});

// the animals it picks from
 var animals = ["elephant", "dog", "monkey", "zebra", 
           "parakeet", "cat", "pig", "gorilla", 
           "skunk", "leopard" ];

// set random animal
function setNewAnimal() {
   var animalSound = document.getElementById("animalSound");
   var x = animals[Math.floor(Math.random()*animals.length)];
   animalSound.textContent =  x;
 }
 
 setNewAnimal();
```

```html
<div id="animalSound"></div>
<button id="reset">Reset</button>
```

Comment: Please select my answer as the correct one then.  Thanks!